# Rails 5 controller test changes - `Devise::TestHelpers` is deprecated and will be removed from Devise.'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, devise

I'm working on my first app since I installed Rails 5. When I ran my specs for controller actions, I got the warning message below even though all my tests were passing.

```
[Devise] including `Devise::TestHelpers` is deprecated and will be removed from Devise.    
For controller tests, please include `Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers` instead.
```

So in `spec/rails_helper.rb` I change this line:

```
config.include Devise::TestHelpers, type: :controller
```

to

```
config.include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers
```

This change made the warning go away, but now the specs for models are failing. (They were passing before the change.) How should I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: could you add code from one spec to check?

Comment: @neydroid The first answer solved it. All the specs for both models and controllers are passing, and no more warning message. Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should change your `spec/rails_helper.rb` file to the following:

```
config.include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers, type: :controller
```

This will ensure that the `Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers` module is only be included in your controller tests. The reason your model tests are failing is because that module is specific to controller tests.